# Google AutocompleteService getPlacePredictions is not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to initiate a customized autocomplete in my site. I tried using Google's places autocomplete API to achieve that.
I expected to first just output the predictions into logs to verify it is working correctly, but as it seems it doesn't get to the callback function and I don't get any error message to work with. NONE.

I started by adding the Google places library:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[Here-I-Entered-My-API-Key]&libraries=places"></script>
```

Afterwards I tried multiple options:

1. At first I tried with simple Autocomplete request to see any result. I entered the following code:

   ```
   let searchInput = $( ".search-input" )[0];
   autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(searchInput, {
           types: ["address"]
       });
   ```

Doing this resulted with nothing, it didn't show the autocomplete options.

2. In my second try, I tried using the AutocompleteService to just achieve the predictions as I wanted initially and print it in console log. I entered the following code:

   ```
   // Create a new session token.
   let sessionToken = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteSessionToken();

   // Pass the token to the autocomplete service.
   let autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
   autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(
           {
                   input: "Mitt",
                   type: ["address"],
                   componentRestriction: {country: 'de'},
                   sessionToken: sessionToken
           },
           function (predictions, status) {
                   console.log("Query resulted in -> " + status);
                   console.log("Received " + predictions.length + " predictions");
                   for(let prediction of predictions){
                       console.log(prediction);
                       console.log(prediction.description);
                   }
           }
   );
   ```

Just in order to verify that it is showing me a result, but as it seems, it doesn't reach my callback function.

I tried copying examples from other usages that I saw online, didn't work either. I can't understand what is going on.
My API key is functional, I have enabled my Places library in GCP (although I didn't see the usage of trying to achieve this inside the GCP usage.).
There isn't any error that I can use to understand what the issue might be, it just doesn't work.

I tried using with my API key the places REST API and it worked, but I don't want to mess with cross-origin requests and I don't think it should be necessary in this specific case.

I would really appreciate an assistance.
Thanks!

Comment: You should file a support case.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it.
Apparently what caused this issue was one call to google api libraries and one call to google api for map callback.
Need to combine it together as following:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[Here-I-Entered-My-API-Key]&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```